# Java Applet stops after starting execution

Tags: java, swing, applet

I have developed a Java Applet which has the functionality of uploading multiple files .

Currently , three files while be uploaded to the server simultaneously.

The problem which I faced :

i> On some occassions , the Java Applet hangs while uploading the files. I have kept a detailed log on the Thread state & on the Http upload classes but not getting exception trace on it when the Java Applet execution stucks/hangs.

With Internet Explorer ver 8  , the Java Applet hangs very frequently whereas with Mozilla Firefox or Google Chrome , it hangs occassionally.

Can the browser proxy settings block the Java Applet at times ?

If so , how can I avoid or bypass the proxy settings ?

Comment: *"Can the browser proxy settings block the Java Applet at times?"* I don't think that is the way they should work normally.  Perhaps the user (or the system admin.) might change proxy settings in the system occasionally, but it is not intended to be 'random & intermittent', as the case seems with your applet.

Answer (score 2):

Verify that you are using [*Initial Threads*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) correctly. An example may be found [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/subway). This mandate applies to applets, as well as applications, and blocking in your (undisclosed) upload protocol likely compounds the problem.